# Settings bundle not showing up in iPhone settings

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, settings-bundle

I am trying to add a Settings bundle in my iPad app, but it randomly shows up in the iPad settings menu.

When I run in Debug mode (Device or Simulator) it doesn't show up.
When I build in Distribution mode and then deploy the app on the iPad A it shows up but doesn't on iPad B (I have several iPads to test).

I am sure the Root.plist is correct as it works sometimes and sometimes not. I also tried with the default plist created when you add a Settings bundle.

Is there something I forgot to do apart from adding the Settings.bundle in the project?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

I've had this problem a few times now.

On the simulator; do a 'Reset Content and Settings', clean, and redeploy.

On the device; delete the app, clean, and redeploy.

**EDIT:** It's also important to make sure that your settings bundle has been added to the current target. That oversight can be very difficult to debug.

Comment: I just wanted to add something: Another option that worked for me is creating the Settings.bundle file right inside Resources, and to LEAVE the default name: "Settings.bundle".

Comment: Try to close System Settings App: double-click the Home button to see recently used apps. Select System Settings App and then swipe up on the app to close. After that run System Settings App again. System Settings App refresh own content.

Comment: To reiterate what @Josh said, make sure the bundle is named exactly "`Settings.bundle`".  In hindsight, this seems obvious, but it had me stuck for a while.

Comment: Regarding "making sure your settings bundle has been added to the current target." this is under Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources (at least in Xcode 9.3).

Answer (score 121):

**iOS Settings App Bug Workaround**

If all of the other answers don't work for you, try using the App Switch UI (double-press Home button, or swipe up from bottom bezel) to **kill the Settings App.**

After everything else didn't work, this fixed the issue for me.

**App Store Installs & Older iOS Versions**

While I have not tested the hypothesis, I suspect, based on all of the other answers, that this has been an issue for several versions of iOS.

Rather, I think it has everything to do with how the App is installed. Apps installed via the App Store do not appear to exhibit this behavior while Apps installed via Xcode or similar side-loading mechanisms appear to never notify the Settings App that there is a new `Settings.bundle` available.

Launching the Settings App from scratch always seems to work, however.

Comment: Yeesh, this release is awful buggy. Thanks! This saved me a lot of time.

Comment: Still not fixed in iOS 9.1.

Comment: Apparently this was discussed in Apple forums too and the same solution was given by TungstenT https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9853

Comment: Reboot the device completely to recover settings.

Comment: @marcel rebooting the device completely will cause the Settings App to be relaunched correct? If so, that's not surprising but it is not a permanent solution.

Comment: When i rebooting my device all settings are displayed. I know it's not a nice solution. I hope apple will solves this problem

Comment: Are there any better workarounds for this yet? Its been a while. It seems like this is effecting MDM installed apps as well :(

Comment: None at present. My guess is that not enough people have filed this as a bug on Apple's Radar, or maybe most people don't even realize it's a bug that needs to be filed.

Comment: is there an open radar?

Comment: This can happen if you device runs out of space. Reboot fixes it.

Comment: @JoãoNunes Yes, restarting fixes it because that forces the Settings app to be restarted which triggers a reload of the `Settings.bundle` for all apps.

Comment: @ThuggishNuggets normally you just need to restart the app. But running out of space messes up the app. So a reboot is needed

Answer (score 15):

While you are adding setting bundle please do not rename it. It should be "Settings.bundle" only. Do not alter it.

Comment: I hate when people do this but thank you, sir! This totally helped me, and this was my issue.

Comment: Same here. Couldn't get my bundle to show up at all, then reverted the name back to the default "Settings.bundle" and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Thank's. THIS definitely works: "Settings.bundle"

Answer (score 4):

What you are going to want to try is to Delete the application off of your iPad devices, and open the simulator and go up to the top menu and click the button "Reset Content and Settings". Then reinstall your application to your devices and the simulator and it should all be working now.

Comment: This solved my issue now on XCode 7.1 five years later, thanks @macintosh264

Comment: For app settings to appear on the iPad I had to reboot it as well.

Answer (score 3):

I noticed the same problem on the Simulator. At the first launch of Settings.app, the pane wasn't there, at subsequent launches it was. It the problem intermittent for subsequent launches of Settings.app? Is the problem dependent on the locale of the device?

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to add a Settings bundle in my iPad app, but it randomly shows up in the iPad settings menu.

One way this can happen is if you reinstall the application on the device while the Settings app is running. For example, the Settings app will display your app's settings content the first time you run it from Xcode, but then it disappears the second time, for not obvious reason.

The easy solution is to **kill the Settings app** and launch it again, and you'll see your app's settings right there were you expect them.

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling that this isn't the exact same issue that you're experiencing, but I found that the adding a Settings.bundle to an existing project required a relaunch of the Simulator before the Settings app picked up on my app's bundle.  Restart the Simulator, not just the app within the Simulator.

Not sure about the actual devices, but I wonder if there's a similar rule there?

Comment: This may be because relaunching the Simulator kills the Apps running on it, including the Settings App which has a bug where it doesn't reload the `Settings.bundle` of an App installed outside of the AppStore while it is running. Killing the Settings App appears to resolve the issue. http://stackoverflow.com/a/32791771/868193

Answer (score 1):

Old question, new answer--hopefully it helps.

My settings were no longer showing.  I deleted my settings and then recreated them by hand and then diffed them.  I found that I was missing

```
<key>StringsTable</key>
<string>Root</string>
```

near the top of my Root.plist file.

Maybe it's a new wrinkle with iOS9.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, there is an error in your settings, but XCode doesn't do a great job of warning you of this, it will just not deploy the (updated) bundle. I had this when adding a new Multi Value. I had forgotten to add the "Values" section. No errors, app will build onto the device, but the Settings will not be updated.

You still want to make sure that you close from the settings app (double tap home, and remove it from the list of resident programs) completely after you rebuild, to ensure the Settings app reads your bundle anew.

Comment: I just realized this was my problem... and then found your answer here. Thanks for posting this though!

Answer (score 0):

On iPhone, delete and install app. You have to run the app once to see the settings.

Answer (score -2):

I think you should Clean all targets , empty all caches delete the previous build,Quit the simulator and rebuild the code.Im sure this will work.