# iOS Settings Bundle Issue

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

Odd issue:  I have a custom settings.bundle with my iOS app.  If the settings app is open when the app is installed (as an Ad Hoc via HockeyApp), the custom settings are not visible.  The systems settings (use cell data, location services, etc) show up fine.  However, fully closing the app and the Settings app then relaunching the app causes the custom settings to show up.  Seems more like an iOS bug than an Appcelerator issue to me.  Anyone else seen this?  Any thoughts?

Comment: This might well be an iOS bug indeed:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/32791771/4626813

Comment: The issue's been there for a long time. Not sure why Apple doesn't do anything about it. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/9853